# Dynamically Show/hide directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement some directive, which will be based on the value of one variable in other Service. Here is my code:

```
        if (this.SomeService.variable.condition){
            element.show();
        } else {
            element.hide();
        };
```

However, it is called only once, when the page is bootstraped. How can I make it so that if the variable changes, the element shows/hides? Is there any way to do it without watcher?

Comment: @Gianmarco, I've tried that, and whenever I toggle the variable.condition, it doesnt change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-show / ng-hide that are angularjs construct used to hide or show a particular piece of HTML.

For example:

```
<div ng-show="true">HELLO I AM THE FIRST DIV</div>
<div ng-hide="true">HELLO I AM THE SECOND DIV</div>
```

will return something like

> HELLO I AM THE FIRST DIV

Inside ng-show you can put watherver kind of variable so then if your javascript is something like this:

```
angular.module('mymodule').controller('MyCtrl',[function(){
    var self = this;
    self.isVisible = true;
}]);
```

you can use that variable in your code:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MyCtrl as c">
    <div ng-show="c.isVisible">HELLO I AM THE FIRST DIV</div>
    <div ng-hide="c.isVisible">HELLO I AM THE SECOND DIV</div>
</div>
```

And the result is the same